# Issues with intense data transfer over USB 3.0

Tags: hard-drive, usb, performance

Edit: TL;DR at the bottom.

---

Edit2: Even shorter, and Mac-specific:

Is there anything I can tweak in a 2014 MacBook Air BIOS that has to do with USB performance, data throughoutput in particular? If yes, how do I do that?

---

Edit3: **Likely solved.**

I went ot system information and found this:

BRCM20702 Hub:

Product ID:   0x4500
Vendor ID:    0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.)
Version:  1.00
Speed:    **Up to 12 Mb/sec**
Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Location ID:  0x14300000 / 4
Current Available (mA):   500
Current Required (mA):    94
Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
Built-In: Yes

This is my Air's USB hub. Apparently, its super fucking slow (12 megabits per second - 1.5 megabytes/s?). Correlates well with my result of ~10 megabytes/s optimal speed. Do I get it right? Dearest Apple Inc. put this thingy in, while the USB 2.0 speed is supposed to be up to 480 M and USB 3.0 is supposed to be ~5G, and just slapped some fansy 3.0 ports on top? But then, how do I get the transfer speed larger than the bus speed? TIL.

---

It is a kind of a long story, but it gets better as it goes, believe me.

I have a few HDDs which I use externally with USB docks. Everything works great until it does not.

In particular, if I try rsyncing, say, 100GB from one dist to another - there's a solid chance it will go south via freezing the disk and/or the machine.

My current setup is a Mac OS running VirtualBox with CentOS in it, the latter doing the dirty work. This pervy setup comes from the fact of me using NTFS on some of the drives. Back in 2012 this was the only cross-platform file system with large file support and an undelete option, at least for Linux and Windows. IIRC, ExFAT was bad back then. Later, I bought a Mac, where NTFS support is pain, and thus here I am.

In the middle of organising my files, I've had a situation where the data transfer stopped (as monitored by iotop), and the terminals froze: cannot ^C rsync, cannot cd, cannot su. Ok, whatever, off-and-on-again the drives, reboot the guest OS, try again. It goes well for some time, but then it happens again. At this point I start suspecting bad blocks at one of the drives and run badblocks on it - and yet again it freezes. TBH, there might be some, I just don't know at this point.

Roughly around the same time, I remember that used to have this very issue long time ago, with an ATA drive and a poor quality cheap dock cable. Back then, I though the cable was the culprit. But, I keep this thought for later: I've got a block of data on one of the new drives, and I want to make a copy of it onto another new drive.

The new drives are both ExFAT, thus I rsync from MacOS directly. Cue big surprise, when the rsync terminal freezes, the transfer speed goes to zero, the drive gets spun down (or just gets silent, not sure), and the file manager shows me an infinitely long waiting cursor when I try to open the target disk. Turning the dock off and unplugging it does not help. I try rebooting the system - and it freezes with a black screen and another "please stand by" rotating thingy! Hard reboot, after the startup there was a period of time of some system processes heavy CPU usage - clearing HDD caches as I've guessed from their names.

At this point I finally start suspecting something, and go google for it. I found [this](https://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/406615-my-computer-freeze-hang-locked-up-when-under-usb-3-0-load-solution.html) and [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2233004-hdd-dock-station-freezes-windows-10). Apparently, the problem might be with either Inter USB3 chip, and/or some BIOS settings. Currently, I'm running another rsync from the guest OS (it's easier to handle if it freezes) with the bandwidth limit of 15M (the stable top speed I was getting is 50M). My idea of what was happening: I was overflowing some cache at some point.

That did not help, although resulted in a new kind of symptom: an eventual i/o error.
I've switched to a USB 2.0 cable, and got some stable transfer over night - which got an i/o error. This time, however, disconnecting the cable resulted in proper spin down of the disks, which made me able to turn them off correctly, turn them on and resume.

Any chance I can tweak anything in my MacBook Air BIOS to avoid this? Any other ideas? What is happening anyway?

At least I hope this was an emotional read.

---

Edit: Added a short description.

I'm transferring a bunch of data between two hard drives connected via USB docks.
Used methods: rsync or ddrescue.

Problem: at some point, the transfer halts (zero I/O rate) and one of the disk lights indicates a constant access.

The halt may or may not come with some degree of a freeze to the system doing the transfer. High transfer speed (~50M average) corresponds to a higher probability of the halt (happens after fewer data transferred). The lower speeds are ~15M for a USB 3 cable, and about ~10M for a USB 2 cable.

It seems that ~10M is the maximal average speed at which the setup works. With that both disk lights show short blinks, with only occasional longer (up to several minutes) write-off periods.

Happens on both USB 3 and USB 2 cables. Happens with both disks in the same two-slot dock, as well as the disks in separate docks.

Source disk can have some degree of a damage, it is not clear.
Destination disk is brand new. It also happened once or twice with two new disks.
The system is MacBook Air, stock (built-in) USB 3 ports. In most cases, CentOS in a Virtual box does the data transfer.

Comment: What does freeze, CentOS or macOS? Also, can you edit the question down to focus on current setup and problem (it‘s kind of hard to figure this out currently)? Most of the backstory is probably not directly relevant.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. The system running the data transfer freezes.

Comment: If it freezes with macOS as well, can we just remove CentOS from the picture here? Also, which version of macOS, which specific Mac model?

Comment: I'm more comfortable with linux progs, and it's easier to reboot the VM (if anything). It's an early 2014 Air, MacOS 10.12.6.

Comment: I understand this. But this is an Apple-focused site, and if the problem already is visible within macOS-triggered transfers, it doesn't help in terms of error analysis and answers if we look at CentOS. It rather is a clear indicator that CentOS itself isn't the problem.

Comment: "CentOS itself isn't the problem" - that is what I think too. It's either the dock, or the USB controller. Also, I cannot elimiante CentOS right now as I will have to deal with NTFS at MacOS level, which I do not want to even try. But, I will have the drives in exFAT eventually. I expect the same behavior though.

Comment: IMHO the main issue currently is that there are too many variables at play, so any answers are difficult to give. I probably would start with HFS/APFS formatted drives and run tests from macOS. If this already freezes, start analyzing. If this works, add *one* additional layer and repeat.